# tags: "fourier" vs "fourier-analysis"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags that seem to mean the same thing. Should we merge them? If yes, what should be the main tag?

- [fourier](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fourier)
- [fourier-analysis](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fourier-analysis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd vote for fourier-analysis being the main tag

Comment: Oh, no.  Then I cannot add the tag to a question asking about Joseph Fourier’s favorite singer!  Joke aside, I am not sure if I am comfortable with tagging a question about discrete Fourier transform with [fourier-analysis], although they are related.

Comment: If you can ask a question about Fourier's favorite singer and have it not be closed, I will concede :)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I think Fourier analysis does encompasses both continuous and discrete cases: [1](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-3-0348-0115-7), [2](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~wperkins3/fourier/), ... we can also consider [tag:fourier-transform] :)

Comment: I think fourier-transform is a little more localized to the actual transform itself.

Comment: @Kaveh: Continuous vs discrete is fine, but tagging Fourier transform as [fourier-analysis] sounds a little confusing to me, at least until I get used to it.  But I do not have a strong opinion.

Comment: Fourier analysis is a very general terms and it is in use in mathematics: for sure, it encompasses (continues or discrete) Fourier transforms (cf [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis)); it is also a MO tag. Since it looks like we are mostly quantum people in the thread, I guess the term can sound peculiar to us since we are used to think of the Fourier transforms as gates used in quantum algorithms (or applications for information processing in general).

Comment: Still, people from other fields who work with Fourier transforms and are focused on their applications could also be confused about this point. Perhaps if we also had a tag for Fourier transforms people would use it naturally.

Comment: @Juan, we can make [tag:fourier-trasnform] a synonym if we decide to go with something else. Are you suggesting it as the main tag? (if so could you please post it as an answer?)

Comment: No, no, I also agree on using fourier-analysis as main tag. I already voted. I was just commenting on @TsuyoshiIto point of view.